# Powershell call class on a string?

Tags: powershell

Trying to call this class to reverse a string in powershell, but can't figure out how to call it.. very simple question but not sure how to do it

```
class Reverse{
[string]$Stringy

[string]Reversi(){
return $(this.Stringy[-1..-$Stringy.length] -join "")
}
}
```

Then i am not sure how to call this class. By itself, the return statement does the job, but i need to call the class, please help, no hints just point to the code there is no help online.

Comment: You have to *instantiate* an object off that class. There is plenty of help online. Unfortunately, this is not a website where you simply ask for answers.

Comment: Do you really need a class for this? It could be easily done with a function.

Comment: That's not a function. As a class, this is not class. A class with a single non-mutable method is not really a class at all. So, ditto to what `Santiago Squarzon` said. There are tons of examples all over the web about PowerShell functions and PowerShell classes. As well as on Youtube. [PowerShell Functions](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powerwshell+functions) and here for [PowerShell Classes](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powerwshell+classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need a class with an instance method?

If you change the method to be `static` instead, you can pass whatever string value as a method parameter and get your result without having to create an instance of the class:

```
class ReverseClass {
    static [string] Reverse([string]$string){
        return -join $string[-1..-$string.Length]
    }
}
```

Now you can call it using the static member operator `::`:

```
PS ~> [ReverseClass]::Reverse("hello")
olleh
```

Comment: this worked without a call to ".\filename.ps1", something is preventing the script from loading in i'm not sure what it is

Answer (score 4):

*My poor attempt to answer this question*, as [Abraham pointed out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750928/powershell-call-on-a-string/68751121#comment121502658_68750928), you need to create an instance of the class:

```
class ReverseClass {
[string]$Stringy

    ReverseClass([string]$String){
        $this.Stringy = $String
    }

    [string]Reverse(){
        return -join $this.Stringy[-1..-$this.Length()]
    }

    [int]Length(){
        return $this.Stringy.Length
    }
}
```

```
$z = [ReverseClass]'Hello World!'
$z.Reverse() # => !dlroW olleH
```

Again, I insist, a class is an overkill for what you need to do:

```
function Reverse-String([string]$String){
    -join $String[-1..-$String.Length]
}
```

```
Reverse-String 'Hello world!' # => !dlrow olleH
```

---

If this class was stored on a file like `C:\users\user\my documents\script.ps1` and you wanted to load the class or function to your current session you would need to [dot source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) it (*simply add a dot before the path*). This will load all everything, classes, functions, variables, etc to your current scope.

For example:

- If your current directory is not where the script is stored:

```
. "C:\users\user\my documents\script.ps1"
```

- If you changed directory to `my documents` in this case:

```
. .\script.ps1
```

Comment: That looks similar to the lectures, but they also did it following with ".\filename.ps1", then "$z = New-Object ..." i'm not sure what to put for ...,  for example ' ReverseClass "Hello World!" ' since neither your statement or mine works. For your statement it says "unable to find type [ReverseClass]", for my statement it says "verify assembly containing this type is loaded".

Comment: This works when not loaded from a .ps1 file. Again sorry i am new to powershell, there is barely any help online and i don't understand what the error prompts above mean

Comment: @user136128 see my last edit hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

This...

```
class Reverse{
[string]$Stringy

[string]Reversi(){
return $(this.Stringy[-1..-$Stringy.length] -join "")
}
}
```

...is not a PowerShell function. This is how you declare a function in PowerShell.

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Short description
.DESCRIPTION
   Long description
.EXAMPLE
   Example of how to use this 
.EXAMPLE
   Another example of how to use this 
#>
function Verb-Noun
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        [string]$Param1,
        [int]$Param2
    )
}

# calling the function
Verb-Noun -Param1 '' -Param2 ''
```

For strings, there is no reason to explicitly cast them as strings. Anything thing in quotes (single or double), is automatically seen as a string.

This is all documented in the PowerShell help files...

```
 Get-Help -Name About_functions
```

... and MS Docs.

Though you can do classes in PowerShell v5 and higher. As documented in the Powershell help files...

```
 Get-Help -Name About_classes
```

... and MS Docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Reverse{
    [string]$Stringy
    [string]Reversi(){
        return  $this.Stringy[-1..-$this.Stringy.length] -join ""
    }
}
```

PS C:> $reverse=New-Object  Reverse -Property @{Stringy="Hello World"}

PS C:> $reverse.Reversi()

dlroW olleH